# Finding $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(x+y)}{x+y}$ by L'Hopital's rule

Tags: limits

I want to find:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(x+y)}{x+y}$$

Can I say that:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(x+y)}{x+y} = \lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\sin u}{u}$$

Then use L'Hopital's rule to find that the limit is $1$?

Comment: Apply L'Hôpital to compute the limit of $\sin u/u$ when $u\to0$? Wouldn't this be paradoxical?

Comment: The limit doesn't exist because the function isn't defined in a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: @Showhat: We don't need it to be defined in a neighborhood, just a punctured neighborhood, relative to the domain of the function.

Answer (score 1):

As far as using L'Hospital's rule, I would instead observe that $$\frac{\sin u}{u}=\frac{\sin u-\sin 0}{u-0}.$$ Hence, what does the limit as $u\to 0$ give us?

As regards the larger question, you can prove that the function $$f(u)=\begin{cases}\frac{\sin u}{u} & u\ne 0\\1& u=0\end{cases}$$ is continuous, as is the function $g(x,y)=x+y$. Hence, their composition is likewise continuous, which is exactly the given function. By continuity, the limits pass through, and you obtain the desired result.

**Added**: There is a bit of a sticky issue: namely, how your limits are defined. If for a function $f:E\to\Bbb R$ (where $E\subseteq\Bbb R^2$) and a limit point $(x_0,y_0)$ of $E,$ we define $\lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)}f(x,y)=L$ is defined by $$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0:\forall(x,y)\in E,\Bigl[0<\bigl\lVert(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)\bigr\rVert_2<\delta\implies\bigl\lvert f(x,y)-L\bigr\rvert<\epsilon\Bigr],$$ then it's perfectly fine to proceed as I described above.

If, on the other hand, it is defined by $$\forall\epsilon>0,\forall(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2,\exists\delta>0:\Bigl[0<\bigl\lVert(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)\bigr\rVert_2<\delta\implies\bigl\lvert f(x,y)-L\bigr\rvert<\epsilon\Bigr],$$ then we cannot do this. In fact, we would be unable to talk about the limit of a function at *any* boundary point of its domain, so I suspect that the former definition (or one like it) is intended.

Comment: I think the intent of the question is about whether replacing $x+y$ and the two variable limit by the single variable $u$ is justified, and not about how to evaluate the final limit. The OP demonstrates understanding of how to evaluate the final limit.